# Threading, Copied, Error, SetTextCallback

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

To try to get a mental grasp on threading, I tried monkey-see-monkey-do, and copied (like read and type, not cut and paste) from [THIS_PAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHINVALIDOPERATION.WINFORMS.ILLEGALCROSSTHREADCALL%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) on MSDN.

When I did that, I got the following errors

> Error 2 The type or namespace name 'SetTextCallback' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Form1.cs 385 17 ZYX987
>
> Error 3 The type or namespace name 'SetTextCallback' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Form1.cs 385 41 ZYX987

I scrolled down aways on the web page and found a lot of community comments indicating that everyone has the exact same problem because the example is misleading. i.e., `SetTextCallback` is never declared.

This is the copycat version I typed while staring at the MSDN page...

```
private void SetText(string text)
{
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of
    // the calling thread to the thread ID of the 
    // creating thread.  If these threads are different, 
    // it returns true
    if (this.label1.InvokeRequired)                    
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        this.label1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Would someone here please suggest where I should place `SetTextCallback` in my CopyCatCode ?

Second question: what does the syntax for declaring it look like ?

Third question: if `SetTextCallback` is a method, then what should be in it ?

I searched for "...SetTextCallback ..." (no quotes) here on Stack Overflow and found a few references, but not this exact problem. Hope this is the kind of question that belongs here. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scroll down in the msdn page you linked to ("[How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHINVALIDOPERATION.WINFORMS.ILLEGALCROSSTHREADCALL%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)"), the full source is listed at the bottom. You'll find there the definition:

```
    // This delegate enables asynchronous calls for setting
    // the text property on a TextBox control.
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
```

Comment: up near the top of the class ?  I mean, before the methods and stuff ?

Comment: Bingo, got it thanks. I Think I voted you up.  Tomorrow, work resumes. I'm going to sleep and will examine the help from the other two in the morning. Thanks for your help, and thank you to the other two also

Answer (score 3):

SetTextCallback would simply be a delegate with the same signature as the method it is delegating.

Like:

```
public delegate void SetTextCallback(string message);
```

You may also benefit from [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the full example for this:

```
// This delegate enables asynchronous calls for setting
// the text property on a TextBox control.
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this is my solution

I was reading serial port with datareceived and just needed put the text received in text box and I did this:

```
public void puerto_serie_DataReceived(object sender,
                                   System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  string a = this.puerto_serie.ReadLine().Trim();
  leer(a);
}
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
void leer(String b)
{
  if (valores.InvokeRequired)
  {
    SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(leer);
    this.Invoke(d, new object[] { b });
  }
  else
  {
    valores.Text += this.puerto_serie.ReadLine().Trim()+"\n";
  }
}
```